# Using disk.frame, but still reaching memory limit issue

Tags: r, correlation, hmisc, r-bigmemory, disk.frame

**Problem:**

I am trying to perform a correlation test on a large dataset: the `data.table` can exist in memory, but operating on it with `Hmisc::rcorr()` or `corrr::correlate()` eventually runs into the memory limit.

```
> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.1 Gb
```

So, I moved to using the filebacked `disk.frame` package to solve this, but I still am reaching the memory limit.

Any advice on how to use `disk.frame` or another package dealing with big memory to achieve this is much appreciated.

*Both `rcorr()` and `correlate()` take and operate on the whole dataset. The dataset contains `NA` values, hence my need to use these functions as they allow handling of missing values with `"pairwise.complete.obs"`.*

**Attempts:**

```
# Packages ----
library(corrr)
library(Hmisc)
library(disk.frame)
library(data.table)


# Initialise parallel processing backend
setup_disk.frame()

# Enable large datasets to be transferred between sessions
options(future.globals.maxSize = Inf)


# test_DT is a data.table of ~18000 columns and ~800 rows
# of type `num` (`double`) 


# Create filebacked disk.frame ----
test_DT_df <- as.disk.frame(
  test_DT, 
  outdir = file.path(tempdir(), "test_tmp.df"),
  nchunks = recommend_nchunks(test_DT, conservatism = 4),
  overwrite = TRUE
)


# `Hmisc` correlation test by chunks ----
# DOES NOT WORK (memory limit issue)
test_cor <- write_disk.frame(
  cmap(
    .x = test_DT_df,
    .f = function(.x) {
      Hmisc::rcorr(
        x = as.matrix(.x),
        type = "pearson"
      )
    }
  ),
  overwrite = TRUE
)
# Bring into R (above code fails before this line is reached)
test_cor_collect <- disk.frame::collect(test_cor)


# `corrr` correlation test by chunks ----
# DOES NOT WORK (memory limit issue)
test_cor <- write_disk.frame(
  cmap(
    .x = test_DT_df,
    .f = function(.x) {
      corrr::correlate(
        x = .x,
        use = "pairwise.complete.obs",
        method = "pearson"
      )
    }
  ),
  overwrite = TRUE
)
# Bring into R (above code fails before this line is reached)
test_cor_collect <- disk.frame::collect(test_cor)


# Cleanup ----
delete(test_DT_df)
delete(test_cor)
rm(test_DT_df, test_cor, test_cor_collect)
gc()
```

Comment: What is the size of your data exactly?

Comment: The ```data.table``` object in memory is 94.2 MB. The ```disk.frame``` files in storage are in total 89.9 MB. I forced the ```Hmisc::rcorr()``` function to be able to complete execution on the ```data.table %>% as.matrix``` by running ```memory.limit(size = 56000)``` beforehand (this took some time with much disk threshing); this produced the resulting object in memory of 5.3 GB.

Comment: Yes, my question was to get a sense of the number of columns that you have. Because the correlation is square of that. You should look at packages bigmemory and bigstatsr (disclaimer: I'm the author of bigstatsr) if you want to store some data on disk (here the result I guess). Then you can loop over all the pairwise variables and store the result in the on-disk matrix.

Comment: Thank you. It is ~18000 columns and ~800 rows. I tried ```bigmemory``` and ```bigstatsr```, but ran into difficulty ([bigmemory issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69848972/how-to-perform-hmiscrcorr-with-big-memory-data-in-r)). I don't think it handles data with ```NA``` values (I need to use ```"pairwise.complete.obs"```, so can't remove all rows containing ```NA``` from dataset beforehand). I would appreciate seeing an example of how to loop over the pairwise variables in the method you describe to store it on disk.

Comment: Just a loop over all columns (i, j, i < j), where you then compute correlation between variable i and variable j and store it in res_i,j and res_j,i.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm afraid I still find that difficult to follow. I'm assuming you mean 2 nested for loops (i, j), but I don't understand what is meant by i < j ? I don't understand why there are 2 objects being stored, and what goes into each? Is it possible to demonstrate the code in an answer, even if it's just the skeleton?

Answer (score 1):

An answer to explain my comment "Then you can loop over all the pairwise variables and store the result in the on-disk matrix.":

```
res <- bigstatsr::FBM(4, 4)
for (j in seq_len(4)) {
  for (i in seq_len(j - 1)) {
    corr <- Hmisc::rcorr(iris[[j]], iris[[i]])
    res[i, j] <- res[j, i] <- corr$r[1, 2]
  }
  res[j, j] <- 1
} 
res[]
```

Comment: Many thanks @F. Privé. The ```FBM``` does not hold ```dimnames```. How can I apply the ```dimnames``` to the ```res[]```? My intention is to create the output in long format. Is there a way to structure ```res``` so that the pairwise ```i``` and ```j``` all exist in 2 columns with ```corr$r``` in a 3rd column. But if that's not possible then I'm thinking to use the ```melt()``` of ```as.data.table(res[])```), however I still need to apply the correct ```dimnames``` to ```res[]``` for it to work.

Comment: By long format, you mean storing, i, j, and r_i,j? Just store it like that directly then.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for your patience with my questions. Can I check, is this the correct interpretation of your previous comment: ```res[i] <- res[j] <- corr$r[1, 2]```? Secondly, how could I apply ```names``` (indicating the columns compared) to ```res[]``` so that they are in the correct order?

Comment: I don't understand what you want exactly. And `res[]` is just a standard R matrix.

Comment: Essentially I'd like to have the output be a ```data.table```/```data.frame```... with 2 columns corresponding to the ```colnames``` of the dataset (e.g. ```iris```) being compared, followed by a column for ```corr$r```, ```corr$P```, and ```corr$n```.